# LDAP Authentication for Camel + restlet app

Tags: spring-security, ldap, apache-camel, restlet-2.0

I have a Camel application which using camel-restlet for web service calls.  now I want to add ldap authentication for restlet calls.  tried couple of options with camel-restlet realm,  LdapVerifier using ChallengeAuthenticator.  can not make it work!  need help?  Thanks

I am able to add LDAP authentication to restlet by using LDAP SecretVerifer.  but if the restlet call is wrapped by Camel route (using org.apache.camel.component.restlet.MethodBasedRoute). The SecretVerifer did not triggered.

Here are some codes and config:
web.xml:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>RestletServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringServerServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>org.restlet.component</param-name>
    <param-value>RestletComponent</param-value>
  </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>RestletServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

CamelContext.xml

```
<bean id="RestletComponent" class="org.restlet.Component">
    <property name="defaultHost" ref="defaultHost" />
</bean>

<bean id="challengeAuthenticator" class="org.restlet.security.ChallengeAuthenticator">
    <constructor-arg><null /></constructor-arg>
    <!-- Sets the Challenge scheme parameter to the static class member -->
    <constructor-arg value="#{ T(org.restlet.data.ChallengeScheme).HTTP_BASIC }" />
    <constructor-arg value="restletRealm" />
    <property name="verifier" ref="ldapVerifer" />
     <property name="next" ref="application" /> 
</bean>

<bean id="defaultHost" class="org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringHost">
    <constructor-arg ref="RestletComponent" />
    <property name="defaultAttachment" ref="challengeAuthenticator" />
</bean>

<!-- Restlet application -->
<bean id="application" class="org.restlet.Application">
    <!-- Sets the router for the application -->
    <property name="inboundRoot" ref="router" />
</bean>


<!-- Used to map routes to Restlet resources -->
<bean id="router" class="org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringRouter">
    <property name="attachments">
        <map>
            <entry key="/user/{name}">
                 <bean class="org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringFinder">
                    <lookup-method name="create" bean="userServerResource" />
                </bean>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="RestletComponentService"  class="org.apache.camel.component.restlet.RestletComponent">
<constructor-arg ref="RestletComponent" />
</bean>
```

LdapVerifer.java

```
@Service(value="ldapVerifer")
public class LdapVerifer extends SecretVerifier {

@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(LdapVerifer.class);

@Override
public int verify(String userName, char[] password) 
{

    logger.debug("Start authenticating login user : " + userName);
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    StringBuffer pd = new StringBuffer();

    for(int i = 0; i < password.length; i++){
        pd.append(password[i]);
    }
    try {
        Authentication authenticate = authenticationManager.authenticate(new    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userName, pd.toString()));
        if (authenticate.isAuthenticated()) 
        {
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticate);
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            logger.debug ("Authentication for login user " + userName + " succeed. the    process time is: "  + (endTime - startTime) + " milliseconds");
            return RESULT_VALID;
        }
    }
    catch (AuthenticationException e) 
    {
        logger.error("Failed to authenticate login user: " + userName, e);
    }
    return RESULT_VALID;
}
```

Here is the output for restlet routings:

```
Jul 23, 2014 10:05:44 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: RestletServlet: [Restlet] Attaching restlet:      org.restlet.security.ChallengeAuthenticator@1ee53046 to URI: /medbus
Jul 23, 2014 10:05:44 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: RestletServlet: [Restlet] Attaching restlet:  org.apache.camel.component.restlet.MethodBasedRouter@6f52bffd to URI: /medbus/wf/query/{id}/{includeResult}
Jul 23, 2014 10:05:44 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: RestletServlet: [Restlet] Attaching restlet: org.apache.camel.component.restlet.MethodBasedRouter@681b8815 to URI: /medbus/wf/query
Jul 23, 2014 10:05:44 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: RestletServlet: [Restlet] Attaching restlet: org.apache.camel.component.restlet.MethodBasedRouter@34717fcf to URI: /medbus/wf/reprocess/{id}
```

if you access URI not in camel routes,  the Ldap authentication was kicked in,  but if you access the URI in the camel routes.  ldap authentication was not triggered at all .
for example,  if you call /medbus/user/name, it works fine, but if you call/medbus/wf/query,  no authentication.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post some code and maybe errors?

Comment: I ended up creating my own secureRestlet by overriding camel restlet component and several package-level classes and private methods.  I injected LDAPVerifier into the secureRestlet.   Right now if you use endpoint like “secureRestlet:” , it will trigger ldap auth.  If you use endpoint like “restlet:”, no ldap auth happens.

Comment: sorry I missed the fact that you added code and an errors. WHy not post the answer down below.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating my own secureRestlet by overriding camel restlet component and several package-level classes and private methods. I injected LDAPVerifier into the secureRestlet. Right now if you use endpoint like “secureRestlet:” , it will trigger ldap auth. If you use endpoint like “restlet:”, no ldap auth happens.